# It's ok to propose a tag through meta while i don't have enough reputation?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

The reputation requirement is low, but I don't meet the requirement yet. Should I propose it here or wait until I get the needed reputation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The questions should be correctly tagged. So if you feel that there's no tag that would really pass to your question, don't wait, but write here what tag do you propose and why.

There are 2 possibilities.

1) Someone with high reputation will create tag and retag your question.

2) Someone will write explanation, why the tag should not be created, and which of the existing tags are more appropriate.

No matter which of those would happen, asking on beta is highly recommended.

Comment: perhaps "beta" => "meta", on the last line? Should i edit this question adding the information about the question and the tag i refer to or simply write a new question? Thanks for the feedback

Comment: I accepted this one as i think it is the simplest and better answer for a future user that may read this Q&A and have this doubt.

Comment: The discussion can be continued [here](http://meta.freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/99/activity-related-tags)

Answer (score 7):

Requesting that a new tag be created before the question has been asked seems a bit… backwards.

New tags are created out of necessity, based on suitability of the questions asked. So it's much better to simply to ask your question… and *then* either 'flag' it for moderator attention or discuss the question here… in meta.

That way we can look at an *actual* use case to see if the tag is warranted.

Comment: Actually i have made 2 questions on `Freelancing` and both should be tagged with more descriptive tags that the ones i used. Regarding this question about tag proposal, do you think i should flag for mod attention the questions or just propose the tag and discuss the question here, on `meta`?

Comment: @laconbass If you feel the tag addition is pretty obvious, self-explanatory, and straightforward, I'd probably 'flag' for moderator attention. If you feel it needs more discussion, then meta is your place.

Comment: we can continue discussing [here](http://meta.freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/99/activity-related-tags) :D

Answer (score 3):

Go for it and just propose it (in another question) - if and when we get Moderators *pro tempore*, they'll be able to deal with the queue of requests for tags that we didn't add during the private beta period.

Another team that can deal with this are the Stack Exchange Community Managers, or even a few of the highest rep users (who also frequent meta). Meta is the correct place for this.