# Activity related tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

Continuing the discussion from [this question i asked before](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93/its-ok-to-propose-a-tag-through-meta-while-i-dont-have-enough-reputation), i'm going to propose **activity related tags**

This tags would refer to a concrete sector or activity, something like `software-development`, `graphics-design`, `photography`, and so on

An example of use could be [this question i made on Freelancing SE](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/381/agile-methodologies-when-developing-software-as-a-freelance). It could perfectly fit a `software-development` tag.

There are plenty of question cases that an activity related tag would be useless, but there are lots of cases too where it makes sense, i think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These broad, catch-all categorization tags tend to be heavily used, overused, and abused — which means they tend to become *THE* dominant tags on the site… all without actually describing what the question is about. That can actually *hurt* the site when your most-used tags don't actually describe the content folks are searching for. That's because a really valuable piece of search-engine data becomes ubiquitous and largely useless.

So unless your question is actually *about* the **subject** of photography (or software-development, or graphics-design, or what have you), I would avoid using and encouraging tags that don't actually describe the *content* of the question.

If the sector you are working in adds important context to the question, you should include that information in the *body* of your text; not in the tags.

Comment: I'm not an expert on SE sites so your arguments are valid for me.